# Example of Google Indexing API Batch Request using .NET

Tags: .net, google-indexing-api, batch-request

Please can someone provide example code in C# that will allow me to submit a batch request to the Google Indexing API for the URL_UPDATED action? The code below shows what I currently use to perform a single URL_UPDATED action using a single HTTP Request.

Ideally, I would like to supply a string[] of Urls that can be passed to the batch function.

Thanks.

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GoogleServiceAccounts
{
  public class Indexing
  {
    public GoogleServiceAccount _googleServiceAccount;
    private IConfigHelper _configHelper;
    private GoogleCredential _googleCredential;
    private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public Indexing(IConfigHelper configHelper, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
      _configHelper = configHelper;
      _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
      _googleServiceAccount = _configHelper.Settings.GoogleServiceAccounts.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name == "Indexing");
      _googleCredential = GetGoogleCredential();
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> AddOrUpdateJob(string jobUrl)
    {
      return await PostJobToGoogle(jobUrl, "URL_UPDATED");
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CloseJob(string jobUrl)
    {
      return await PostJobToGoogle(jobUrl, "URL_DELETED");
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostJobToGoogle(string jobUrl, string action)
    {
      var serviceAccountCredential = (ServiceAccountCredential)_googleCredential.UnderlyingCredential;

      string googleApiUrl = "https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish";

      var requestBody = new
      {
        url = jobUrl,
        type = action
      };

      var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

      var configurableMessageHandler = new ConfigurableMessageHandler(httpClientHandler);

      var configurableHttpClient = new ConfigurableHttpClient(configurableMessageHandler);

      serviceAccountCredential.Initialize(configurableHttpClient);

      HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

      var response = await configurableHttpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(googleApiUrl), content);

      return response;
    }

    private GoogleCredential GetGoogleCredential()
    {
      var path = _hostingEnvironment.MapPath(_googleServiceAccount.KeyFile);
      GoogleCredential credential;

      using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
        credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing" });
      }

      return credential;
    }
  }
}
```