# .NET Core 3.1 - HostingEnvironment does not contain a definition for MapPath

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, google-api-dotnet-client, google-indexing-api

I am using .NET Core 3.1 and I am trying to connect to the Google's Indexing API by presenting a private key. I have looked at things like: [Example of Google Indexing API Batch Request using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53817560/example-of-google-indexing-api-batch-request-using-net) and https://hamidmosalla.com/2019/12/07/using-google-indexing-api-with-google-api-client-library-for-net/

Here is my code:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Requests;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Indexing.v3;
using Google.Apis.Indexing.v3.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal;

public static class MyClassDownloader {
    public static GoogleCredential GetGoogleCredential()
    {    
        string path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/PrivateKey/myprivatekey.json");
        GoogleCredential credential;
    
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing" });
        }
    
        return credential;
    }
}
```

However, I am getting an error on the line regarding `MapPath`:

```
'HostingEnvironment' does not contain a definition for 'MapPath'
```

I have tried looking into `IHostingEnvironment`, after which I learned it was deprecated for `IWebHostEnvironment`. How do I get the proper physical path for my JSON file regardless of if I am in development or production?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: Personally, I would simply pass `IWebHostEnvironment` as a parameter to the `GetFileStreamData()` method.

Comment: @UweKeim Good point. I modified my posting to give a bigger picture of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change `MyClassDownloader` to not be static and add a constructor that takes `IWebHostEnvironment` as a parameter which would be saved in a variable inside `MyClassDownloader`. Then, `MyClassDownloader` needs to be registered in `Startup.ConfigureServices()`. Finally everywhere `MyClassDownloader.GetGoogleCredential()` is called (e.g. in controllers), an instance of `MyClassDownloader` needs to be available. This instance is made available through injecting it into the using class' (e.g. the controller) constructor.

Example (I did not test that code):

```
// MyClassDownloader.cs
// Make MyClassDownloader non static and add constructor
public class MyClassDownloader 
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment;

    public MyClassDownloader(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment) 
    {
        this.webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
    }

    // Method not static any more
    public GoogleCredential GetGoogleCredential()
    {    
        // Depending on the hosting OS you might have to use backslash but I'm
        // not sure about that
        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
            webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, 
            "/PrivateKey/myprivatekey.json");

        GoogleCredential credential;
    
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing" });
        }
    
        return credential;
    }
}

// Startup.cs
public class Startup 
{
    // ... some code

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ... some code
        
        // Register newly non static MyClassDownloader so it can be injected
        // into classes that need it.
        services.AddTransient<MyClassDownloader>();

        // ... some more code
    }

    // ... some more code
}

// GoogleCredentialConsumer.cs
// Sample class that needs an instance of GoogleCredential. 
// To obtain the GoogleCredential instance, it needs a MyClassDownloader. 
// Might be a controller or another class
public class GoogleCredentialConsumer 
{
    private readonly MyClassDownloader myClassDownloader;

    public GoogleCredentialConsumer(MyClassDownloader myClassDownloader)
    {
        this.myClassDownloader = myClassDownloader;
    }

    public void MethodThatNeedsGoogleCredential()
    {
        var theGoogleCredential = myClassDownloader.GetGoogleCredential();
        // yay, finally I have it!
    }
}
```